# Amazon S3 to SSIS data flow

Tags: amazon-s3, ssis

I'm trying to download a file from amazon S3 with a particular file name via SSIS

Can anyone please suggest me which transformation will help me do that , Below are the details I have in hand from Amazon s3

1. access_key_id
2. Secret_access_key
3. Bucket_name
4. region

sorry cannot share values right now.

Answer (score 0):

**Amazon S3 configuration :**

By default, the SSIS package does not allow you to connect with the AWS S3 bucket. It does not mean that we do have any mechanism to do so.
But you can browse Visual studio Marketplace and use [Amazon S3 SSIS Components](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KingswaySoft.ssisamazons3) (SSIS Productivity Pack).
It enables SSIS package and Amazon S3 SSIS bucket integration without writing any specific code. You can easily use this SSIS productivity pack to download complete the task effectively and efficiently.
Download the appropriate 64-bit or 32-bit. Double-click on the installer and follow up the installation wizard for installing SSIS productivity pack with default configurations.

**S3 bucket connection :**

The first step is to create a connection pointing to the Amazon S3 bucket. Right-click on the connection manager and choose New connection:

Create a connection pointing to the Amazon S3 bucket. Right-click on the connection manager and choose `New connection`.

You need to connect with the `AWS S3 bucket` so select the `Amazon S3` and click on Add. It opens the `Amazon S3 Connection Manager`.

In General page of the connection manager, you need to specify connection properties and login credentials to the AWS S3 bucket:

You need to store the `access key` and `secret key` in a secured location. Specify it in the Amazon S3 Connection Manager. It authenticates user account in Amazon services using these keys, and you can see the bucket name in the drop-down list :

[image]

**Add a Data Flow task :**
Add a data flow task in the SSIS package for the Amazon S3 SSIS bucket.

Double-click on the task, and it takes you to the data flow screen. In the SSIS toolbox on the data flow tab, you can see options for Amazon S3 bucket:

- Amazon S3 Destination
- Amazon S3 Source
- Premium Flat File source
- Premium Flat File destination

Drag `Premium Flat File Source` in the data flow task from the SSIS toolbox:

[image]

Double-click on Premium Flat File Source and it opens the editor window for configuration:

- Connection Manager: Select the existing connection to the S3 bucket from the drop-down. If you do not have an existing connection to the S3 bucket, click on New. You require specifying keys (access and security key) information, as shown in previous steps.
- Source File Path: It is the CSV file path in the S3 bucket. Click on eclipse and browse to the CSV file path. You might have multiple files in the S3 bucket. The source file path should point to a valid CSV file.

Click on eclipse (…) on the source file path and browse to the CSV file path:

[image]

You can see the CSV file in the Source item path column.

- The first row has the header: My CSV file first column contains column headers. Remove the check from here if the CSV file does not contains headers
- Skip Empty Rows: CSV file might contain empty rows. Put a check on this to skip the empty rows

[image]

Click on columns tab to view excel file columns. You can uncheck the columns if you do not want to import them into SQL Server tables. It also shows the data type and length automatically.

You can change the column data types and their properties in this window. For this demonstration, let’s go with default columns properties in the Amazon S3 SSIS package:

[image]

Click OK and add an `OLE DB destination connection`. This `OLE DB destination` should point to the `SQL Server instance` for example. Right-click and configure the destination with the `SQL Server connection` and `SQL Server table`. You also need to do the mapping between source and destination columns:

[image]

Once the `OLE DB destination` connection is successful, you can see the package as shown below:

[image]

Execute the SSIS package, and it transfers 100 rows from the source CSV file to SQL Server table.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation